# Div repeats after auto-refresh

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, ajax, jsp

I have two divs in my jsp page:
1) headerdiv, which contains a form with the radio button. (coloured blue)
2) maindiv, which contains the table in which data from database table is inserted.

I want the table in my 'maindiv' to be refreshed, so as to update the dynamic data. Also, there is a jQuery code for generating random colors to the table which is dynamically changing for every 5 seconds, with the help of a jQuery AJAX code.

This is the screenshot of my JSP page before auto-refresh occurs (the ideal, preferred layout):

[Before the auto-refresh happens](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XlZAY.png)

But, once the auto-refresh starts, the top div part (which I named as 'headerdiv') gets repeated again in the 'maindiv'. 
[After auto-refresh](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sfxtb.png)

Here are the snippets from the JSP page:

The auto-refresh part:

```js
     <script>     
      function autoRefresh_div()
 {
      $("#content").load("index.jsp");
  }

  setInterval('autoRefresh_div()', 5000); // refresh div after 5 secs
</script>
```

The random color generator part:

```js
    <script>
    function get_random_color() {
    var letters = '0123456789ABCDEF'.split('');
    var color = '#';
    for (var i = 0; i < 6; i++ ) {
        color += letters[Math.round(Math.random() * 15)];
    }
    return color;
}

$(function(){
    paint_rows();
});

function paint_rows() {
    $('#content tr').each(function(){
            $(this).css('background', get_random_color());
    });
}

</script>
```

Is the problem with the auto-refresh part? I also have used CSS styling to the various elements in both 'headerdiv' and 'maindiv'. Does it have anything to do with the repeating div?

Comment: Try `$("#content").empty().load("index.jsp");`

Comment: what's inside index.jsp ?

Comment: you have to use `setInterval('autoRefresh_div', 5000);` without brackets. As of your code it calls immediately first time and not for other times. It makes difference between **calling** of function and assign **call back**. @Sri

Comment: @Sri i hav mentioned in setInterval `'autoRefresh_div'`